# iOS Fastest QR code reading method?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, qr-code

i need some advice about developing app using QR code scanner's libraries on iOS.
I am already bit familiar with iOS7 AVFoundation framework, Zbar and Zxing.

My goal is to use method that can scan QR code in **the shortest time possible**.

I am thankful for any experience shared or tips how to improve the scanner performace.

Comment: Those are all libraries. Can't you test them yourself and see which is fastest for what you need? Of the top of my head, I'd go with AVFoundation, Apple's code is usually very optimised.

Comment: I can, but i can also ask on the page designed for it and save hours of time for me and maybe some other people. It this does not help i can try the other way...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [CDZQRScanningViewController](https://github.com/cdzombak/CDZQRScanningViewController) which uses iOS7 only API - is this what you are looking for?

Have you noticed a performance issue with the other libraries? maybe you could elaborate on the issue you are having.

Comment: I actually tested performance only using AVFoundantion, it is not exactly an issue, but there is some delays in scanning due to camera focusing etc., there was some codes that i cant read at all (mostly small ones)